# xguest with Biometric validation

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

A server is connected to 'dummy' terminals (all-in-one computers) in an isolated network. These terminals have xguest account that are directly connected to the server. Access to the server is through browser only. However, I need to authenticate independently the user using biometrics. So, can I use client to activate biometric device directly or by using some daemon? Which approach would be preferable? I am planning to use fingerprinting as it seems to be easier of all with adequate safety. I would be grateful for any further suggestions or inputs for the problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: First you need a fingerprint reader. Then you need to [configure the system to use it](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System-Level_Authentication_Guide/authconfig-addl-auth.html#fingerprints).

Comment: The problem is, from what I read, xguest does not support authentication. So would this be useful?

Comment: xguest_u is an SELinux user, which is different from a UNIX user.

Comment: So, the suggestion is to use a normal user with SELinux xguest_u configuration and fingerprint authentication? If so then the user may try to open shell or other applications... Or are you suggesting a script-based browser launching after authentication?

Comment: I thought you were asking about authenticating with a fingerprint?

Comment: I was asking for a confined/jailed user from a client that needs fingerprint authentication either at login or, preferably, which submitting some data entered during the session using a browser. Sorry that it was not clear.